Replacing axis labels with scale_x_discrete
Consider this plot
dat <- data.frame(Sample = c(rep("S01", 3),
                            rep("S02", 3),
                            rep("S03", 3)),
                  Class = as.factor(c(rep(c("A", "B", "C"),3))),
                  Abundance=c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3))

dat <- rbind(dat, dat, dat)
dat$Transect <- as.factor(c(rep("x", 9), rep("y", 9), rep("z", 9)))
dat <- rbind(dat, dat, dat, dat)
dat$Season <- as.factor(c(rep("Ap", 27), rep("Ma", 27), rep("Au", 27), rep("Se", 27)))



ggplot(dat, aes(Sample, Abundance, fill=Class)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_bar(col="black", stat="identity", width=0.75) + 
  facet_grid(Season~Transect)

it is not possible to relabel the x-axis with the labels argument within scale_x_discrete by names given in an additional column, so that S01 is replaced with 100, S02 is replaced with 200, and so on:
library(plyr)

dat$Distance <- revalue(dat$Sample, c("S01" = "100",
                                      "S02" = "200",
                                      "S03" = "300"))

ggplot(dat, aes(Sample, Abundance, fill=Class)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_bar(col="black", stat="identity", width=0.75) + 
  facet_grid(Season~Transect)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = dat$Distance) # note that labels=Distance is not working

All axis labels are set to the first level of the naming factor.

Note, that in my much more complex real life data, it is not possible to switch to aes(x=Distance), because of the presence of 4 replicates per Sample, which for unknown reasons prevents the plotting of the bars. Also, putting labels = Distance into aes is not working. To the same end, dat$Sample cannot be made a factor. All these approaches would not result in the desired plot.
I think the culprit is the labels = dat$distance argument, as ggplot2 doesnt know the correct alignment of Distance and Sample, but using labels = Distance results in "object 'distance' not found".
I can build a data frame with a unique mapping with
labs <- unique(as.data.frame(cbind(dat$Sample, dat$Distance)))
names(labs) <- c("Sample", "Distance")

but do not know ho to proceed from there.
Is it possible to have my axis labels replaced with scale_x_discrete?
/edit: As my original data contains ~250 levels of dat$Sample, which are sorted into 5 groups of dat$Distance, it would be possible but tedious to write a complete vector of 250 relabels into scale_x_discrete (thanks to @MrFlick)

Do you just want scale_x_discrete(labels=c("S01"="100", "S02"="200", "S03"="300"))?

Yes, thanks, but my real life data has ~ 250 levels of Sample, of which ~50 belong to one group of distance.

So you are trying to make bar plots with 250 bars? or 50 bars? I don't understand. Is the Distance column in your input data or are you just adding it here in your example? You seems to be listing all the groups in the revalue anyway. Otherwise what's the mapping rule?

You can programmatically build the list samplenames <- unique(dat$Sample); samplelabels <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(samplenames)*100), samplenames) and then use scale_x_discrete(labels=samplelabels)

MrFlick, that is already very close, but my 250 samplenames are sorted into 4 groups (500, 200, 100, 25).

From your question, I don't see how to map those 250 names to those 4 values. You have to define the mapping somehow.

I can e.g. create a data.frame with new.dat <- unique(as.data.frame(cbind(dat$Sample, dat$Distance))), but i dont know how to add this the labels-argument in scale_x_discrete.

Don't ever use cbind() inside an as.data.frame. That leads to coercion problems. If you have new.dat <- unique(dat[,c("Sample", "Distance")]) Then use samplelabels <- with(new.dat, setNames(Distance, Sample))

# use a named character vector 
labels  <- c("S01" = "100",
             "S02" = "200",
             "S03" = "300")

ggplot(dat, aes(Sample, Abundance, fill=Class)) +
  geom_bar(col="black", stat="identity", width=0.75) + 
  facet_grid(Season~Transect)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels)


possible, but tiring with 144 individual sample names

Create the labels programtically:
names = paste0("S", sprintf("%03d", 1:144))
values = as.character((1:144)*100)
labels = setNames(values, names)

If the samples are numbered you can play around with seq in the labels argument of scale_x_discrete
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(dat, aes(Sample, Abundance, fill=Class)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_bar(col="black", stat="identity", width=0.75) + 
  scale_x_discrete(label = seq(100, 300, 100)) +
  facet_grid(vars(Transect), vars(Season))


Created on 2024-06-18 with reprex v2.1.0
